What did the changeSite keyword do before AX 7?
So I gather from here that X++ used to support a keyword called "changeSite". According to this blog, the keyword was removed as of AX 7.
After looking for some time, I've been unable to find any reference or explanation to what specifically the changeSite keyword did when it was part of the X++ language.
I'm hoping someone more experienced with AX 7 can tell me what it used to do, and ideally link to some documentation about it.
Update
After concluding that "changeSite" was a mistake in documentation, I opened PR #5006 in MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-unified-operations-public to remove it from documentation. I also opened PR #64 in MicrosoftDocs/Dynamics-365-Operations.ja-jp, where changeSite was also mentioned.
The misconception seems to have spawned from an article from the blog ax7dev from January 10th, 2016, which was then commited into official docs by a Microsoft employee on August 27th that same year.

You need someone with access to AX 2012 or 2009 to check that for you as that keyword is not available in D365. I don't remember using it in any version of AX starting with Axapta 3.0. I am inclined to think it's just a mistake in the release notes.

I'd like to add the context of this post I made on D365 community https://community.dynamics.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=dfb68320-7f90-ef11-ac21-6045bdd3c2dc which recieved a reply showing that changeSite was not a keyword as of AX 6.3 either. I don't discount the possibility that it did exist at some point before AX 2012 R3.

You already established that the changeSite statement didn't exist in AX 2012 R3 CU12 (released 21 November, 2016).
I have also verified that this statement is not mentioned in the following comprehensive volumes from Microsoft press:

Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009
Inside Microsoft Dynamics AX 4.0

I haven't encountered it in any other Axapta / Dynamics AX / Dynamics 365 materials since 2003.
This is most likely to be a mistake in the release notes.
The only other place I see this information copied is in this blog post from 18 January, 2016: https://ax7dev.blogspot.com/2016/01/dynamics-ax-7-development-whats-new-in-x.html - however, the author wasn't a Microsoft employee, so he must have copied it from the announcement by Microsoft.

Thanks for that. Just to add for context: The AXForce post seems to be a word-for-word copy of ax7dev's post (created 8 days earlier). The relationship between the 2 sites seems clear, but AXForce sites ax7dev and ax7dev links to AXForce on their blogspot site.

axforce had a few authors, one of which had the ax7dev blog
